# What does "Error when writing Schema: A unique destination featuretype name could not be generated for" mean?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gml, data-interoperability

I have a bunch of GML datasets which I need to import to Esri featureclasses. I am using the Data Interoperability extension for ArcGIS, which should support this. However when trying to import my features I get the following error:

"Error when writing Schema: A unique destination featuretype name could not be generated for """

Thanks

Here is a snippet of the code:

-  
-  
- http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd" gml:id="zones">
- 
- 
- 
- 
  inspireId 
  UK_zone 
  
  
- 
- 
  eng 
   
   
   
   
- 
- 
  Teesside Urban Area 
   
  
  
  
  
- 
- 
- 
-

Comment: Do you know whether your GML is of Simple Feature profile? http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32381  If it is not, then I think it ceases to be a simple matter to import.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for responding, how can I tell if it is in fact in SF format? Sorry I am quite new to this. Here is a snippet of the code:

Comment: I'll have to leave answering how to recognize GML-SF to someone more OGC literate than me but for an entry point to ArcGIS 10 documentation on its support for GML this may be a useful URL http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_GML_support_in_ArcGIS/003700000004000000/

Comment: @AlexOulton Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message, but added a pointer to the XSD file that defined my GML schema (e.g. xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wwwwwwwww.com GML.xsd") in the FeatureCollection tag, and of course ensured the XSD file was in the same directory, and all was fine.